# What kind of coffee machine can process powdered coffee?

Tags: espresso-machine, coffee-machines, turkish-coffee

I have a drink I like to make using powdered coffee, a coffee grind finer than espresso. but when I try to make it in an espresso machine, the powder expands, and only the first few drips come out. (its delicious) Then the espresso machine will nearly explode, as the heat builds, and the pressure cannot escape.

what is out there for high pressure espresso machines?  I would also like to make a gaurana drink in a similar fashion, but I think it would be the same issue, with tiny particles expanding when wet, and clogging the holes in the press.

To be perfectly clear, I mean very fine ground coffee, which is in a powder, and not freeze dried coffee.

Comment: “Powdered” as for Turkish coffee? Are you familiar with that process? And: Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, such coffee is ground for Turkish. If this is the case, you may try to prepare your coffee in a pot. If you are really considering (somewhat) automated machine, you may go for Turkish coffee machines. Keep in mind, that they don't prepare coffee as good as an experienced human; but they are nice enough to drink. I put an image of one of those, so you can search it on the web.

[image: Arçelik Telve, Turkish coffee machine]

Comment: I didnt know there was a turkish coffee machine, i hadnt even considered that. But what if I dont want to drink the grounds?

Comment: @j0h I believe you don't need to drink the grounds if Turkish coffee has been properly prepared. Grounds should not swim, but accumulate at the bottom. Otherwise, still you don't want to drink Turkish, you may give this a try: place a thin piece of filter paper before putting the grounds in the basket. This may end up increased pressure, so it is better to be extremely careful. Please let us know if you could manage a proper cup.